# Supertab shall not be used on my abbreviation settings

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, supertab

I have installed [Supertab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) in vim. Now I face the circumstance that my abbreviations does not work as normal. Which would be: I write the abbreviation `atn` and it expands to `@todo-next`. Now I have to hit `Tab` and `Enter`, so that the expandation works.

How can I get the iab work as before?

Here an extract of my abbreviations.

```
# :iab
i atn @todo-next
i ato @todo
```

Comment: Just quickly looking through the [documentation for the plugin](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab/blob/master/doc/supertab.txt), it looks like there's an `g:SuperTabNoCompleteAfter` option. Does that work?

Comment: I checked the part of the documentation. Way a) for `g:SuperTabNoCompleteAfter` can handle specified text pattern, this is not usefull. Way b) works with a function reference, so basically I would have to write a function which checks every pattern against my abbreviations. I didi hope to find a easier solution ...